# Vim: Match whitespace between braces but not on new lines

Tags: regex, vim

In vim I'm trying to highlight whitespace after a `(` and before a `)` in `.coffee` files.

so that in `( foo = true, bar = false )` the method would highlight the **space** before `foo` and after `false`.

Here's what I have:

```
highlight BraceWhiteSpace ctermbg=red ctermfg=white guibg=#592929
fun! UpdateMatch()                                               
    if &ft !~ '^.*\.coffee$'                                     
        match BraceWhiteSpace /([ \t]\+\|[ \t]\+)/               
    else                                                         
        match NONE                                               
    endif                                                        
endfun                                                           
autocmd BufEnter,BufWinEnter * call UpdateMatch()
```

the critical part is here

```
match BraceWhiteSpace /([ \t]\+\|[ \t]\+)/
```

this works, except it also matches a brace with leading whitespace on a new line, which I don't want:

```
    )
```

I'm struggling to write a regex that has a lookbehind to check it's not at the start of the line.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Lookbehind to check if it  is not the start of a line should be just `^\@<!` (or if it is not at the start of the pattern, use `\_^\@<!`)

Comment: So then my full pattern would be `/([ \t]\+\|^\@<![ \t]\+)/` ? That isn't working for me, it matches everything after the first space on the line with just spaces before the brace.

Comment: Then, you can make it a bit longer: `[ \t]\+)\(^[ \t]\+)\)\@<!`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked, you should post it as an answer

Comment: Ok, posted with a bit of explanation.

Comment: Note that you could make this regular expression shorter by substituting  `\s` for `[ \t]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution with a lookbehind placed *after* the `)`:

```
[ \t]\+)\(^[ \t]\+)\)\@<!
```

The `\(^[ \t]\+)\)\@<!` only checks if there is no start-of-line followed with 1+ blanks followed with `)` after it matches 1+ blanks with a `)`.

The full expression:

```
([ \t]\+\|[ \t]\+)\(^[ \t]\+)\)\@<!
```

Answer (score 0):

give this line a try:

```
match BraceWhiteSpace /([ \t]\+\|.\+\zs[ \t]\+)/
```