# Match whitespace between curly brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have this line of text:

```
This is {{some.     test}} to see     if I can remove spaces
```

I want this line of text using regex:

```
This is {{some.test}} to see     if I can remove spaces
```

I have tried [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304394/vim-match-whitespace-between-braces-but-not-on-new-lines) to get into the right direction and although I can match all the multiple spaces with `([ \t]+[ ])+` I dont know how to match only if it's between `{{` and `}}`.

How do I modify my current regex?

Comment: So, the regex you need should be working in Vim?

Comment: No, php. I just came across that question while searching for a solution. I use this to check if the regex works: http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all spaces inside `{{...}}` you may match `{{...}}` substrings with `{{.*?}}` regex and replace spaces inside those matches with `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$re = '~{{.*?}}~s'; 
$str = "This is {{some.     test}} to see     if I can remove spaces"; 
echo preg_replace_callback($re, function($m) {
    return str_replace(" ", "", $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/s7gR78)

The `s` modifier will make `.` match newlines, too. If you do not need that (and want to only match `{{...}}` substrings that are on one line, remove `s`.

To replace all kinds of whitespace, use a `preg_replace` inside the callback with `\s+` pattern matching 1+ whitespace characters:

```
preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $m[0])
```